# Speeding up a program through initialization

Tags: java

So for my programming class I submitted an AI program that generated words based on statistics taken from a sample string. However, the following lines of code slowed down the program immensely:

```
//Opens and reads the Dictionary
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("common_words.txt"));
while (inputFile.hasNext()) { 
    wordCheck = inputFile.nextLine();
    if (wordCheck.equalsIgnoreCase(aiWord)) {//Stops dictionary if word is found
         inputFile.close();
         break;
    // ...
```

This process was repeated until a word was created that was included in the word list. My question is, could the process be sped up if I initialised the word list into an array? I figure then I'd be reading off of RAM instead of HDD. I tried to implement this into my code but it was too complicated to splice in >.<

Comment: use a `java.util.List` of word (all uppercase or lowercase if you want case-insensitive search) and `List#contains` maybe

Comment: how large is common-words.txt? If it fits in memory, go with a HashMap

Comment: yeah, if possible read this into a single memory object.  Constantly opening and reading a file is going to be very slow.  If the file is *very* large you may need to come up with some sort of indexing scheme so that the file (or parts of it) can be read more quickly.

Comment: Instead of telling us what you're doing, try to explain what you're trying to achieve. There may be other approaches that you didn't think consider. Further, as markspace mentioned: if you're opening and reading a file for any word the AI generates - you're doing a lot of redundant work: do it once and save the words into a HashSet and re-use that HashSet for the comparison (which should be quicker as well).

Comment: If the file is small enough to fit in memory, then use a `HashSet` as described in Chai T Rex's answer.  If not, could you possibly divide it into a number of smaller files?  One very simple way would be to divide it into 26 files, for words beginning with each letter of the alphabet.  Then, you'd only have to read one of those files for each `aiWord` that you analyse.

Comment: Forgive me I'm new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better for speed to use a `HashSet` that you set up just once using a static initializer, like so:

```java
private static final Set<String> lowerCaseWords = new HashSet<String>();
static {
    final Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("common_words.txt"));
    while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) { 
        lowerCaseWords.add(inputFile.nextLine().toLowerCase());
    }
    inputFile.close();
}
```

The static initializer (the `static {` block) runs only once when the class is loaded, allowing you to load all the words into the `Set` just once when the class is loaded.

---

You can then use the `Set` like so:

```java
if (lowerCaseWords.contains(candidateWord.toLowerCase()) {
    // Is a word
} else {
    // Isn't a word
}
```